# Extending the slider class to accept string value as its maxValue

Tags: java, android, github

I need to use slider from this library https://github.com/florent37/android-slidr
But I need to custom it's max value into infinity (for example by writing string "~").

However, I cannot do it because the value on top right is on only have method that accepting float value.

```
slidr.setMax((float) limit);
```

I want to setMax into unlimited (say 99999999) but on the text on top right I want to show "~" instead of the float numbers.

I can't find out on the slider class when they set the text on the top right.

How can I change the text on the top right to accept string value ("~") and automatically set the float value on limit into 99999999?

If I need to make new class and extend the setMax function to accept string, how should I do it? where exactly the set the text for the top right value since it's only accepting float value as setMax input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can create a [custom text formatter](https://github.com/florent37/android-slidr/blob/545c6d184fb9299ef94aae39b168708777fa1f9f/android-slidr/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/androidslidr/Slidr.java#L1029) and set it on your slider with `slidr.setTextFormatter`. That's how they implemented the samples you see on the [readme](https://github.com/florent37/android-slidr) showing `629 €` instead of a float value.

The implementation would look something like

```java
public class InfinityTextFormatter implements TextFormatter {
  @Override
  public String format(float value) {
    // Replace your MAX here
    return (value == MAX) ? "~" : Float.toString(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it's on there. I don't even need to extend the class.
     slidr.setTextFormatter(new Slidr.TextFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String format(float value) {
                if(value!=(float)999999999)
                    return "Rp. " + df.format((double) value);
                else
                    return "~";
            }
        });